# Trying to create a mid vtx with two fermions (Tiks-Feynman)

Tags: luatex, diagrams, commutative-diagrams, tikz-feynman

So i've been working hard over the past 7 hrs and I am at the point where Tiks-Feynman needs improvement or I just don't get it. This is most likely my 4th question in this forum and I feel real embarrassed.

I need to complete three Feynman diagrams to include in my thesis and so far I haven't been very successful although the learning curve is not too steep.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
 \feynmandiagram [ horizontal=a to t1,baseline=(a4.base)] {
 a  -- [fermion, edge label'={$N$}] t1 [dot] , t1 -- t2 , t1 -- t3 ,t1 -- 
 [fermion, edge label'={$N$}] t4, 
 };
 }
```

and these is what i got:

[image]

And i need to draw these three feynman diagrams as they are, include [dots]:

[image]

Any help on how to draw these diagrams will be appreciated by me and the community (I'm sure)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these diagrams are somewhat hard to obtain with layout mechanism provided by the packages, but very easy done without those algorithms.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt]
\begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a);
            \vertex[right=2.5cm of a](b);
            \vertex[right=2.5cm of b](c);
            \vertex[above=1.5cm of a](d);
            \vertex[above=1.5cm of c](e);
            \diagram*{
            (a)  -- [fermion,edge label'={$N$}] (b) -- [fermion,edge
            label'={$N$}] (c),
            (d) -- [charged boson,edge label={$W^i$}] (b) -- 
            [charged scalar,edge label={$\pi$}] (e)
            };
            \draw[fill=black] (b) circle (2pt);
\end{feynman}
\begin{feynman}[yshift=-3cm]
            \vertex (a);
            \vertex[right=2.5cm of a](b);
            \vertex[right=2.5cm of b](c);
            \vertex[above=1.5cm of a](d);
            \vertex[above=1.5cm of c](e);
            \path (d)--(b) coordinate[midway](f);
            \diagram*{
            (a)  -- [fermion,edge label'={$N$}] (b) -- [fermion,edge
            label'={$N$}] (c),
            (d) -- [charged boson,edge label={$W^i$}] (f) --
            [charged scalar,edge label={$\pi$}] (b) -- 
            [charged scalar,edge label={$\pi$}] (e)
            };
            \draw[fill=black] (f) circle (2pt);
\end{feynman}
\begin{feynman}[yshift=-6cm]
            \vertex (a);
            \vertex[right=2.5cm of a](b);
            \vertex[right=2.5cm of b](c);
            \vertex[above=1.5cm of a,xshift=2cm](d);
            \vertex[above=1.5cm of c](e);
            \path (b)--(e) coordinate[midway](f);
            \diagram*{
            (a)  -- [fermion,edge label'={$N$}] (b) -- [fermion,edge
            label'={$N$}] (c),(b) -- 
            [charged scalar,edge label={$\pi$}] (f)
            --  [charged scalar,edge label={$\pi$}] (e),
            (d) -- [charged boson,edge label={$W^i$}] (f)
            };
            \draw[fill=black] (f) circle (2pt);
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]